# Javascript - Automate duplicating tags from parent div to child div based on class snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, automation

I would like to automate duplicating a class from a parent div to each separate child span based on a word.

As an example:
parent div contains the following classes: grid-item tag-street-style tag-slender tag-classic tag-navy tag-grey tag-white is-loaded

I would like to duplicate any classes within the parent div with the precursor "tag-" and place them into each separate child span. In this case, the parent div contains the classes with the initial "tag-" word: tag-street-style tag-slender tag-classic tag-navy tag-grey tag-white

Some other parent divs will contain other classes that contain the initial word "tag-"

The "tag-" classes can be different in other parent divs but there will always be 5 "tag-" classes. As an example, a different parent div may contain the following classes with the initial "tag-" word: tag-smart-style tag-casual tag-modern tag-red tag-black tag-green

I already have a code snippet but this is locked in to 5 specific "tag-" classes. Here is the code:

```
let classMap = {
    "tag-street-style": ".colour-tag-1",
    "tag-slender": ".colour-tag-2",
    "tag-navy": ".colour-tag-3",
    "tag-grey": ".colour-tag-4",
    "tag-white": ".colour-tag-5",
  };
```

I would like the first "tag-" class identified within the parent div to be duplicated into "colour-tag-1" within the first child span.

Then I would like the second "tag-" class identified within the parent div to be duplicated into "colour-tag-2" within the second child span.

Then I would like the third "tag-" class identified within the parent div to be duplicated into "colour-tag-3" within the third child span.

Then I would like the fourth "tag-" class identified within the parent div to be duplicated into "colour-tag-4" within the fourth child span.

Then I would like the fifth "tag-" class identified within the parent div to be duplicated into "colour-tag-5" within the fifth child span.

```js
$(document).ready( function() { 
  $(".grid-item .grid-meta-wrapper").each(function(e){
    $(this).append('<div class="product-view-item-colour-tags"><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-1">tag1</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-2">tag2</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-3">tag3</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-4">tag4</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-5">tag5</span></div>');
  });
  let classMap = {
    "tag-street-style": ".colour-tag-1",
    "tag-slender": ".colour-tag-2",
    "tag-navy": ".colour-tag-3",
    "tag-grey": ".colour-tag-4",
    "tag-white": ".colour-tag-5",
  };
  for (let cls in classMap) {
      document.querySelector(classMap[cls]).classList.add(cls);
  }
});
```

```css
<style>
.tag-street-style {
    background-color: purple;
}

.tag-slender {
    background-color: red;
}

.tag-navy {
    background-color: blue;
}

.tag-grey {
    background-color: grey;
}

.tag-white {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.tag-red {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}

.tag-black {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.tag-green {
    background-color: black;
    color: green;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid-item tag-street-style tag-slender tag-classic tag-navy tag-grey tag-white is-loaded">
  <section class="grid-meta-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-main-meta">
      <div class="grid-title"> T-Shirt </div>
      <div class="grid-prices">
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>12.99</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-meta-status"></div>
  </section>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="grid-item tag-smart-style tag-casual tag-modern tag-red tag-black tag-green is-loaded">
  <section class="grid-meta-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-main-meta">
      <div class="grid-title"> T-Shirt </div>
      <div class="grid-prices">
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>12.99</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-meta-status"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is a testable solution:

```js
$(document).ready( function() { 
  $(".grid-item .grid-meta-wrapper").each(function(e){
    $(this).append('<div class="product-view-item-colour-tags"><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-1">tag1</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-2">tag2</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-3">tag3</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-4">tag4</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-5">tag5</span></div>');
  });
  let classes = [...document.getElementById("tag-specifier").classList].filter(item => item.indexOf("tag-") === 0);
  for (let index = 0; index < classes.length; index++) {
      let currentItem = document.querySelector(".colour-tag-" + (index + 1));
      if (currentItem !== null) {
          currentItem.classList.add(classes[index]);
      }
  }
});
```

```css
.tag-street-style {
    background-color: purple;
}

.tag-slender {
    background-color: red;
}

.tag-navy {
    background-color: blue;
}

.tag-grey {
    background-color: grey;
}

.tag-white {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.tag-red {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}

.tag-black {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.tag-green {
    background-color: black;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tag-specifier" class="grid-item tag-street-style tag-slender tag-classic tag-navy tag-grey tag-white is-loaded">
  <section class="grid-meta-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-main-meta">
      <div class="grid-title"> T-Shirt </div>
      <div class="grid-prices">
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>12.99</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-meta-status"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Now, let's understand it:

- I have added the `id` of `tag-specifier` to the element which has the classes, so the code will have an easy time finding the classes to work with
- `document.getElementById("tag-specifier").classList` is returning an object of key-value pairs where the keys are indexes (starting from 0) and the values are class names
- I convert the result of `classList` into an array via `[...document.getElementById("tag-specifier").classList]` because I intend to use the `filter()` function of the array, alternatively I could have written a loop with similar effect
- `.filter()` is being called for the newly converted array. This function takes a [callback](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp) (more on that below) that determines which items we are interested about from the array and returns an array that contains only the items that the callback found interesting
- a callback is a function that is scheduled to be executed at some future point of time
- in our case, the callback of `.filter()` is a function which will be executed for each elements of the array and will evaluate them whether they are interesting
- our callback is `item => item.indexOf("tag-") === 0`, which is a function (we use the arrow operator `=>` to differentiate the parameter, which is `item` and the actual function body, which is `item.indexOf("tag-") === 0`), that is, we are only interested about items whose name starts with `tag-`
- after the call for `.filter()`, the value assigned to `classes` is an array of class names that only holds valuable class names from our perspective, that is, class names starting with `tag-`
- we loop `classes` using a variable we create for this purpose, named `index`
- we search for the element that corresponds to the selector of `".colour-tag-" + (index + 1)`. The reason for the `index + 1` is that Javascript arrays are 0-indexed and your tag indexes start from 1
- note that `(index + 1)` is enclosed into parantheses. The reason for this is that `+` is an operator that acts both as concatenator and numeric addition and evaluates from left-to-right, that is, without the paranthesis around `(index + 1)` the result of `".colour-tag-" + index + 1` would be looking like `.colour-tag-01` instead of `.colour-tag-2`
- we check whether `currentItem` exists, so we program defensively, so, if any anomaly occurs, we intend our code to handle it gracefully
- if `currentItem` existed, then we add the current class, which is `classes[index]`

EDIT

The initial solution I have implemented was assuming that we deal with a single such case, while your problem included multiple similar cases on the same page. To solve this issue, I have added an extra layer to the solution, querying the roots of all relevant subtrees in HTML and using them as the context of their respective problem-spaces.

Here is a snippet that illustrates it (yes, the first 3 tags will be unstyled, but this is not due to the logic of the code, but it is rather due to the styling specification of the structure):

```js
$(document).ready( function() { 
  $(".grid-item .grid-meta-wrapper").each(function(e){
    $(this).append('<div class="product-view-item-colour-tags"><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-1">tag1</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-2">tag2</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-3">tag3</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-4">tag4</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-5">tag5</span><span class="product-view-item-colour-tag colour-tag-6">tag6</span></div>');
  });
  
  for (let context of $(".list-grid .grid-item")) {
    let idDeclaration = context.id;
  
    let classes = [...context.classList].filter(item => item.indexOf("tag-") === 0);
    for (let index = 0; index < classes.length; index++) {
        let currentItem = context.querySelector(".colour-tag-" + (index + 1));
        if (currentItem !== null) {
            currentItem.classList.add(classes[index]);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-navy {
    background-color: blue;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-grey {
    background-color: grey;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-white {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-red {
    color: red;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-black {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-green {
    color: green;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-yellow {
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-orange {
    color: orange;
}

.product-view-item-colour-tags .tag-pink {
    color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-grid">

<div id="thumb-product-3-9" class="grid-item tag-street-style tag-slender tag-classic tag-navy tag-grey tag-white is-loaded">
  <section class="grid-meta-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-main-meta">
      <div class="grid-title"> T-Shirt 1</div>
      <div class="grid-prices">
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>9.99</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-meta-status"></div>
  </section>
</div>
<br>
<div id="thumb-product-3-12" class="grid-item tag-social-style tag-thicker tag-premium tag-green tag-black tag-red is-loaded">
  <section class="grid-meta-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-main-meta">
      <div class="grid-title"> T-Shirt 2</div>
      <div class="grid-prices">
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>12.99</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-meta-status"></div>
  </section>
</div>
<br>
<div id="thumb-product-3-1" class="grid-item tag-outdoor-style tag-warmer tag-premium tag-pink tag-white tag-orange is-loaded">
  <section class="grid-meta-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-main-meta">
      <div class="grid-title"> T-Shirt 3</div>
      <div class="grid-prices">
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>14.99</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-meta-status"></div>
  </section>
</div>
<br>
<div id="thumb-product-3-4" class="grid-item tag-street-style tag-slender tag-casual tag-green tag-yellow tag-red is-loaded">
  <section class="grid-meta-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-main-meta">
      <div class="grid-title"> T-Shirt 4</div>
      <div class="grid-prices">
        <div class="product-price">
          <span>15.99</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-meta-status"></div>
  </section>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: good day and thank you so much for this assistance! This is super awesome and I am learning so much from you.

I have created a fiddle that can be accessed here > https://jsfiddle.net/6dmy2sgh/

I tried your solution and there are two issues:

#1 issue - The code seems to only target the very first product within the list of products

#2 issue - You created a specific Id which conflicts with existing Id's that each product already has (I did not include the Id's before because I did not think that this was important).

Comment: I tried to use:

let idDeclaration = $(".list-grid .grid-item").attr('id');

to be placed within:

document.getElementById(idDeclaration)

But still, only the first child product is being targeted.

I appreciate the solution that you developed and it works but only for one child product.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/3ure6zy7/

Comment: @Houghtonator looking into the fiddle. You are correct when you state that my current solution does not handle this when we have plurality of similar cases, as it was focusing an a single such issue, but it can be converted to handle a plurality of cases.

Comment: @Houghtonator so, I have looked into your Fiddle and applied a further layer to the logic, making sure that we have multiple tags that act as roots of the HTML subtree of their problem-space and I queried those elements, looped them and used them as the new context. Here is the updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dgarqt16/1/

Comment: @Houghtonator edited my answer in order to handle a plurality of such cases. Please let me know whether this already qualifies as a solution, or, if there are any problems that were not covered yet. Thanks!

Comment: @Houghtonator Logically, I see the rational reasons as of why you thought that ` let idDeclaration = $(".list-grid .grid-item").attr('id');` would be helpful, the assumption was that you intend to get the ids and use them as the base of the context. But technically this was only handling the first context. The solution I applied was in line with your logic, but it adhered to the technical necessities as well, as I queried the items and looped them, to force the system to take into account the latter elements. So, your thinking was logical and right, but it needed some adjustments.

Comment: I am so grateful for your contribution. Thank you so much for the feedback and the code update. My coding knowledge is a work in progress and I have learned new ideas from you. Is there a way for me to show my support to you?

Comment: @Houghtonator I'm happy to help, the fact that you have got past the problem successfully and understood the solution is by itself a reward for me. Also, when you will be an experienced developer, if you help new developers with their problems, that would be great. Not necessary, of course, it is up to you. But I remember the time when I was a new developer and had no means to ask my questions to more experienced programmers. I intend to help new developers with the issues I had back in the day :)